# How to observe data inside viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have connect my android application to firebase and am using it to retrieve Authentication details and data from firestone. I am using an MVVM architecture and live data for this. The problem is that I need to retrieve email address first and then used this data to query the firestone which contain documents with ID = emailID. You can see my viewmodel. The value for the emailID is null when every I run this. How can I accomplish this while following the MVVP style of coding ?

#Edit: I need to understand how can check if the live data has been initialised with a value in the case where one livedata value depends on the other.

```
class ProfileViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    var random =""
    private var _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val userName
        get()=_name

    private  var _post = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val userPost
        get()=_post

    private var _imgUrl = MutableLiveData<Uri>()
    val userImgUrl
        get()=_imgUrl

    private var _emailId = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val userEmailId
        get()=_emailId


    init{

        getUserDataFromProfile()
        getUserPostFromFirestone()

    }

    private fun getUserPostFromFirestone() {


        val mDatabaseInstance: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
//        _emailId.observe(getApplication(), Observer {
//
//        } )
        if(_emailId.value!=null){
            mDatabaseInstance.collection("users").document(_emailId.value)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        _post.value = task.result?.data?.get("post").toString()

                    } else {
//                    Log.w("firestone", "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
                        _post.value = "Unable to Retrieve"
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun getUserDataFromProfile() {

        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
        random = currentUser?.displayName!!
        _name.value = currentUser?.displayName

        _post.value = "Unknown"
        _imgUrl.value = currentUser?.photoUrl
        _emailId.value = currentUser?.email


    }


}
```

Comment: You do not have to observe . call `getUserDataFromProfile` inside `if (task.isSuccessful)` . You also want to consider using a Wrapper resource for Livedata type otherwise how are you gonna check its status Success fail or In progress ?

Comment: I understand this. I was planing to convert this to coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a wrapper over the Firebase call and expose it as a LiveData (or, in this case, I'll pretend it's wrapped in a `suspendCoroutineCancellable`), in which case whenever you want to chain stuff, you either need MediatorLiveData to combine multiple LiveDatas into a single stream (see [this library I wrote for this specific purpose](https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combinetuple-kt/)) or just `switchMap`.

```
private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

val imgUrl: LiveData<Uri> = MutableLiveData<Uri>(auth.currentUser?.photoUrl)
val emailId: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>(auth.currentUser?.email)

val post = emailId.switchMap { emailId -> 
    liveData {
        emit(getUserByEmailId(emailId))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set `observer` to `LiveData` and remove it when you don't need it:

```kotlin
class ProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _email = MutableLiveData<String>()

    private val emailObserver = Observer<String> { email ->
        //email is here
    }

    init {
        _email.observeForever(emailObserver)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        _email.removeObserver(emailObserver)
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using coroutines for the sequential execution of the code. so once you get the output of one and then the second one starts executing. If this isnt working Please let me know i can try help you.

```
 init{
    viewModelScope.launch{
            getUserDataFromProfile()
            getUserPostFromFirestone()
    }
   }
```